# Выражение "по-любому"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Является ли выражение "по-любому" (в значении "в любом случае") сленговым или все-таки литературным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре написано, что оно разговорное. Я бы не стал относить его к сленговым.

Comment: А что за словарь?

Answer (score 2):

Если понимать сленг в значении "элементы ненормативной речи", то да, сленговые.
Нормативности тут быть не может, во-первых, выражение слишком молодое, а во-вторых, толком никто не знает, что оно значит.

Comment: Похоже, "из той же оперы" модное ныне "по ходу" в смысле "похоже". Довольно глупое сочетание...

Comment: Чтоб я знал, что значит "походу"... Но точно не является полным синонимом "похоже". Максимум - частичным.   
"По-любому" в этом смысле даже понятнее. Всё-таки оно близко к "в люом случае", "любым путём" и проч.

Comment: "По ходу" – это "по ходу дела", то есть либо что-то типа "исходя из настоящей ситуации, можно сделать вывод", либо "одновременно с чем-то, вовремя чего-то". 
1) "Он, по ходу, недалекий" – то есть делается вывод из ситуации.
2) "По ходу в магазин заскочим" – то есть "заодно", "по пути".

Comment: Дерзкий, Вы опять опоздали.

Comment: Первое упоминание в российской литературе :  
> Сергей Осипов. Страсти по Фоме. Книга третья. Книга Перемен (1998) ― Фомин постарался задать этот вопрос, как можно осторожнее, чтобы Доктор не сломал кровать. ― **Да хоть как, по любому!** Он уже спрашивал у тебя о Черте, о твоем замке?

Почему-то всегда и везде суется нечистая сила! Хоть как, да пролезет хвостатая тварь, нигде не опоздает, по любому свою морду обозначит...